# Extracting just a single group from a regular expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to get a list of numbers from some hacked-together log files using zgrep. So, I am using:

```
zgrep -ie "total time: .* ms" *
```

This returns the whole line that I care about. I'd just like the number. (after total time but before the 'ms') Is there any way to get this information without further processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `grep` is the GNU `grep` and assuming the number you're looking for is the only number on the line:

```
zgrep -ioEe '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' *
```

If not, you can always filter `zgrep`'s output:

```
zgrep -ie 'total time: .* ms' * | sed 's/.*total time: \(.*\) ms.*/\1/'
```

Comment: @Jeremy Glad I could help. Please see the updated answer, I improved the `sed` so it's more accurate. I don't know what came over me earlier...

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep, you can combine two features to get what you want:

- the `-o` option to print only the matching part of the line;
- Perl regular expressions and their [zero-width lookaround assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) to limit what may appear before and after the match.

```
zgrep -Pi -o '(?<=total time: )([0-9.]+)(?= *ms)' *
```

Alternatively, you might call Perl.

```
perl -MPerlIO::gzip -e 'for (@ARGV) {
    open IN, (/\.gz$/ ? "<:gzip" : "<"), $_ or die "$_: $!";
    $name = $_;
    while (<IN>) {
        if (/total time: ([0-9.]+) *ms/i) {print "$name:$1\n"}
    }
    close IN
}' *
```

Without these tools, you can iterate over the files manually and call `sed` to strip off everything but what you're interested in.

```
for x in *; do
  case "$x" in
    *.gz) <"$x" gunzip;;
    *) cat "$x";;
  esac | sed -n -e 's/^.*total time: \([0-9.]*\) *ms.*$/\1/p'
done
```